# VBScript: How can I dynamically reference an object?

Tags: vbscript

I have an array of object names. These objects are HTML elements. I want to loop through this array and change each object's properties dynamically, rather than having to write a list of `If Then` or `Select Case` statements.

I am looking at `GetRef()` which would work for functions, but doesn't seem to work for objects.

I am used to python where I can use `getattr()`. PHP's variable variables also work in a pinch. Is there an equivalent in VBScript?

Here's what I would like to be able to do (I know that everything before the comment works -- it's the bit after the comment I need help with):

```
<table id="softwareStatus">
    <tr>
        <td><span id="statusProg1">prog1</span></td>
        <td><span id="statusProg2">prog2</span></td>
        <td><span id="statusProg3">prog3</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script language="VBScript">
    Dim softwarelist(2,2)
    softwarelist(0,0) = "prog1"
        softwarelist(0,1) = "statusProg1"
    softwarelist(1,0) = "prog2"
        softwarelist(1,1) = "statusProg2"
    softwarelist(2,0) = "prog3"
        softwarelist(2,1) = "statusProg3"


    For x = 0 To 2
        if IsInstalled(softwarelist(x,0)) Then
            ' I want to change the object's attributes
            ' by referring to it dynamically:
            softwarelist(x,1).InnerHTML = "<strong>" &_
              softwarelist(x,0) & "</strong><br />Installed"
            softwarelist(x,1).style.backgroundcolor = "white"
        Else
            softwarelist(x,1).InnerHTML = "<strong>" &_
              softwarelist(x,0) & "</strong><br />Not Installed"
            softwarelist(x,1).style.backgroundcolor = "red"
        End If

    Next
</script>
```

**Edit:**

After a few days, I found a solution that works. Since no one has answered my question yet, I answered it myself. I didn't accept my own answer, though, in hopes that someone else will provide a better solution.

Comment: What does your multi-dimensional array look like, which properties  are you trying to change and to what? I suggest you add some of the code that you have already written.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you're looking for a dictionary type? Have you tried `dim dict: set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` (assuming you're developing for Windows and IE)? I've not tried it and not sure this works client-side though

Comment: @oracle certified professional: No, I'm not looking for a dictionary type; arrays work fine. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'm looking for a way to manipulate an object dynamically. Meaning, I'm getting the object's name from a string stored in a variable (see code above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way than my previous answer. It uses a DOM method:

```
softwarelist = Array("prog1", "prog2", "prog3")

For Each prog in softwarelist
    If IsInstalled(prog) Then
        Set objItem = Document.GetElementByID("status" & prog)
        objItem.InnerHTML = "Text here"
    End If
Next
```

Using a dictionary would also work, oracle certified professional was right about that:

```
Set dSW = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With dSW
    .Add "prog1", "divprog1"
    .Add "prog2", "spanprog2"
    .Add "prog3", "uniqueID3"
End With

For Each prog in dSW
    If IsInstalled(prog) Then
        Set objItem = Document.GetElementByID(dSW.Item(prog))
        objItem.InnerHTML = "Text here"
    End If
Next
```

Both of these methods work well, are clearer and more intuitive, allow more flexibility, and allow for the possibility of more customization. I think they also better use the built-in functionality of both VBScript and HTML. `Execute` has its place, but tends to be more of a hack.

Comment: GetElementByID is the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
For x = 0 To 2
    if IsInstalled(softwarelist(x,0)) Then
        Execute softwarelist(x,1) & ".InnerHTML = ""Text here"""       
    End If
Next
```

It gets sort of unwieldy with more complex strings, but it works, and it's the only thing I could find that works.